# Order a MySQL query by the outcome of a certain PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It's easy to order a MySQL table by the value of a certain column of that table. However, say I have a table of posts and a `function score($postID)` in PHP that contains a complicated algorithm that calculates the score of a certain post. Is there a way to order the table by the outcome of that function instead?

One approach that I know will probably work is the following: I add a `score` column to table, and every time something happens with that posts, I call a function that updates the score of that post. Then, I can easily order the table by that `score` column. Is this the way it's most commonly done? Or is there a better way?

Comment: No, MySQL cannot call PHP functions. Read the results into a PHP array, then use `usort` to sort it using your function.

Comment: You could also write a MySQL function that computes the score, then you could use that function in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: "persisting" the calculation is a way to do it and it can be useful - but you need to take care of course that you do maintain (update) that column or it could just be a nuisance. The algorithm you refer to as complex might be transferable into a db function or stored procedure, and that could make it easier to update the column.